# How to change a variable value using choose and when

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to built some rules around a calculated variable value, but am struggling to get the rules to work with an output of false being returned if either or both criteria are used. I need to use both qualifying criteria, but in the process of bug testing tried each argument individually.

I have a variable called "calculation". However when a discount amount is applied to it, I do not want the value of the calculation to be below 301.12. This however is only the case when a discount amount has been applied. If the value of the calculation is below 301.12 without a discount then this is OK, and the lower value is acceptable.

What is happening however is the the lower value after the discount has been applied is still being returned when the process is run.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
        <xsl:variable name="discountAmount">
          <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="@affiliateID='12345'">50</xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="feeAmount">
          <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="@affiliateID='12345'">25</xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>50</xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="grossAmount" select="format-number(db1:grossPremium, '#0.00')" />
        <xsl:variable name="discountGiven" select="($grossAmount - $feeAmount) div 100 * $discountAmount" />
        <xsl:variable name="calculation" select="($grossAmount - $discountGiven)" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$discountAmount &gt; 0">
                <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="$calculation &lt; 301.12"> 
                        <xsl:value-of select="$calculation=301.12" />
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change values of variables in XSLT. Try it like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="calc0" select="($grossAmount - $discountGiven)" />
<xsl:variable name="calculation">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$discountAmount &gt; 0 and $calc0 &lt; 301.12">
      301.12
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$calc0" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: I now get the following error back:   <StatusMessage>1)Source=Affiliate,Procedure=Quote,Desc=Error in Quote2)Source=Affiliate,Procedure=CreateAffiliateQuoteXML,Desc=Error in CreateAffiliateQuoteXML3)Source=System.Data.SqlXml,Procedure=Compile,Desc=XSLT compile error.4)Source=System.Data.SqlXml,Procedure=AddQuery,Desc='boolean($discountAmount > 0 && $calc0 < 301.12)' is an invalid XPath expression.5)Source=System.Xml,Procedure=NextLex,Desc='boolean($discountAmount > 0 && $calc0 < 301.12)' has an invalid token.</StatusMessage>

Comment: Figured it out - replaced &amp;&amp; with the actual word "and", so code now is:<xsl:variable name="calc0" select="($grossAmount - $discountGiven)" />
<xsl:variable name="calculation">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$discountAmount &gt; 0 and $calc0 &lt; 301.12">
      301.12
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$calc0" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>